# React not turning HTML string from JSON into text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am having a problem with React.js and the way it deals with text stored in variable.

Here is how it would look like using DOM:

```js
let text = "Must credit to &quot;https://indepthguide.com/&quot; not Flickr.\nCopy Link Address: <a href=\"https://indepthguide.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\">indepthguide.com/</a>"

document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="root"></p>
```

This is how it looks like in React.js.

```js
var text = "Must credit to &quot;https://indepthguide.com/&quot; not Flickr.\nCopy Link Address: <a href=\"https://indepthguide.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\">indepthguide.com/</a>";

class Text extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h3 >{
      text
    } < /h3>;
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( <
  Text / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I have tried `new DOMParser();` but with no success as it started throwing errors and i am unsure how to deal with it.
I really don't know how to do it, tried doing it for very long now :D.

Comment: That's one of many reasons why JSX sucks. https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, React does not allow create tags from string variables because this is too dangerous.
You could use `dangerouslysetinnerhtml` if it is rly necessary. Please read documentation by this link https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use it?

Comment: @saem Replace `<h3 >{
      text
    } < /h3>` with  `<h3 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: text}} >< /h3>`. Notice that there is `__html` also.

Answer (score 6):

> As a last resort, you always have the ability to insert raw HTML.
>
> `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'First &middot; Second'}} />`
>
> https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html

```js
var text = "Must credit to &quot;https://indepthguide.com/&quot; not Flickr.\nCopy Link Address: <a href=\"https://indepthguide.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\">indepthguide.com/</a>";

class Text extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h3 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:text}} />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Text / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To all other answers it's good to add that you should protect such parts from script injection attacks. The library like [DomPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) should help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is another plugin which helps HTML tags to render on the page.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser

In my opinion, it is a much easier way as compare to dangerouslySet InnerHTML.